# CSS - vertical align text (grandchildren of table)?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I have quite complicated table layout, there is a wrapper set to `display: table`, that has children set to `display: table-cell`. Unfortunately some grandchildren of the table wrapper need vertical-aligment as well. I can't set them to table-cells because it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

**Basically I want to center "t" leters of red buttons.** I don't know height of parent so can't use `line-height` and as it's `inline-block vertical-align` doesn't work as well. And changing their display to `table-cell` cuts their height.

**Here's jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/cZ7Th/5/

CSS:

```
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background: #eee;
}

.logo {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    height: 9rem;
}

ul {
    margin: 0 1rem;
}

.links {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle    
}

.links li {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ddd;
}

.links li a {
    padding: 0 2rem;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="logo">logo</div>
        <ul class="links">        
            <li><a href="#">t</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">t</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">t</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using the `display: table` cell on the logo and ul?  Couldn't you achieve the same thing without that?

Answer (score 1):

Please do as following:

```
.links li a {
    padding: 100% 2rem;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/cZ7Th/16/)